# Gravimetric analysis of barium or sulfate

Tags: analytical-chemistry, precipitation

Which is a better way to obtain barium sulfate precipitate for gravimetric analysis: by adding $\ce{Ba^2+}$ ions to sulfate ion solution, or the other way round? I think it is better to precipitate sulfate ions by $\ce{BaCl2}$ solution, as this causes chloride ions to coprecipitate.

Comment: @Marko use `\ce` to format chemical expressions. Plain math mode gives italicised formulae. [See the "basic chem" section](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/16683)

Answer (score 1):

I think $\ce{BaCl2}$ should be added later. This is because $\ce{BaCl2}$ is soluble in water, but the metal sulphate you will be given may not be soluble. So if you add $\ce{M2SO4}$ later, you may get a wrong result as you have to make sure that the whole of $\ce{BaCl2}$ is used up. On the other hand all chloride salts are soluble. So while filtering the $\ce{MCl}$ will be removed easily along with the solvent and you will get $\ce{BaSO4}$.

Comment: I don't think so. Not all chloride salts are soluble and some sulfates are soluble enough. I want to hear an opinion from the precipitation point of view.